# Dart variables in URL

Tags: url, dart

Is there a way in Dart to fetch variables from the loading URL?

For example, from this URL:

```
 website.com?var_A=7&var_B=192
```

can I retreive the variables `var_A` and `var_B`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse('website.com?var_A=7&var_B=192');
print(uri.queryParameters['var_A']);
print(uri.queryParameters['var_B']);
```

prints

```
7
192
```